# ssh on ubuntu 16.04 crashes after a few seconds

Tags: 16.04, ssh

I have a newly installed ubuntu 16.04 that cannot keep a ssh session for more than about 30 seconds. This is on a local network with several development linux boxes attached.

This hardware had debian 8 previously installed and had no issues with ssh on this same local network.

I typically ssh into another box and run a vi session. Everything is fine for about 30 seconds. Then the vi session freezes, then after an additional 30 seconds the ssh session closes and I am back in the originating terminal.

I have tried both using and not using the -X option but no difference.

Any clue as to what is going on??

Thanks...

Comment: Ethernet or WiFi? Have you tried seeing if you can host an SSH server?

Comment: This is using regular ethernet.  When the ssh session crashes I get the following in the syslog:

Comment: pahoran whoopsie[900]: [11:33:13] Parsing /var/crash/_usr_bin_compiz.1000.crash.
pahoran whoopsie[900]: [11:33:13] Uploading /var/crash/_usr_bin_compiz.1000.crash.
pahoran whoopsie[900]: [11:33:15] Sent; server replied with: No error
pahoran whoopsie[900]: [11:33:15] Response code: 200
pahoran whoopsie[900]: [11:33:15] Reported OOPS ID 9b838b7a-f91c-11e6-86f8-fa163e839e11

Comment: For long output please [edit] your post to include a [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/) rather than leaving a comment which can be deleted for [various reasons](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1343/does-askubuntu-encourage-deleting-old-comments)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had an IP address conflict on my local network with 2 linux boxes configured with the same IP address. Fixing this conflict fixed the ssh problem. It all makes sense now...  :-)